# Confidence interval that starts with 0

Tags: psychology, mplus

I have a confidence interval that starts with 0 (0, 0.8) at the 95% interval. would this be considered significant?

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is important to define your null and alternative hypotheses. For instance, if the null hypothesis is that the parameter equals a billion, that is a different story than if the null hypothesis is that the parameter equals $0.2$. // However, people often sling around this terminology with it implied that the null hypothesis is that the parameter equals zero. If that is the case, what is your concern, that the lower endpoint is exactly equal to zero?

Comment: If suppose you tossed a biased coin $4$ times and saw tails every time, your 95% confidence interval for the probability $p$ of heads might be $[0,0.75]$ using the "rule of three".  That is not a significant result if your null hypothesis is $H_0:p=0.5$ and even less so with $H_0:p=0$ but it is significant for $H_0:p=0.9$

Answer (score 0):

The confidence interval starts only with a rounded value of zero. Here's how to get a more precise value using an example of a regression coefficient with a label 'a':

MODEL:
y on x (a);

MODEL CONSTRAINT:
new(a_big);
a_big = a*10000;

OUTPUT: cinterval;

Now the output for the parameter a_big will have a CI that is 10,000 times as big as the original 'a' parameter. This CI will not start at zero most likely... if it does then just multiply 'a' by 1,000,000 :-)

Comment: Many CI's beginning with 0 do so because the underlying numeric procedure produced a negative value, but the parameter has been restricted to be non-negative.  There's no rounding issue then.  For more precision simply print the original result more precisely: there's no need for any additional calculation.